# JS array splice deleting first element

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, i have an array of pfps:

```
["63c959f37337160e2de8b7e4/20230122173537/profilepicture.png","63c959f37337160e2de8b7e4/20230122173616/profilepicture.png"]
```

And, i want to remove `"63c959f37337160e2de8b7e4/20230122173616/profilepicture.png"` from the list.

But when i run this code:

```
let foundPfp = await pfps.find((pfp: any) => pfp === data.pfpId)
if (foundPfp != -1)
   pfps.splice(foundPfp, 1)
```

then it removes `"63c959f37337160e2de8b7e4/20230122173537/profilepicture.png"`

Can you tell me why? Thanks!

Comment: [`find`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns an Array item or `undefined`. [`splice`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) expects an index as its first argument. Did you mean [`findIndex`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)?

Comment: I somehow feel like you have `pfps: any` or some other weirdness, cause otherwise TS should not let that code slide without an error. Why you `await` `Array.prototype.find` is also a mystery to me.

Comment: Also see: [STACK OVERFLOW QUESTION CHECKLIST](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)  "Have you done some research before asking the question?"

Comment: PS: at first I wondered, why calling `Array.prototype.splice` with a string as first argument won't throw, then remembered, "hey this is javascript, nothing throws". It converts via [`ToIntegerOrInfinity`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tointegerorinfinity), which ends at "Let number be ? ToNumber(argument). If number is NaN, +0, or -0, return 0", that's why it removes the first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but...

**Removing the first element from an array**

```js
let foundPfp = await pfps.find((pfp: any) => pfp === data.pfpId);
foundPfp.shift();
console.log('first element removed', foundPfp);
```

**or if you want to remove a specific element from an array:**

```js
const pfps = ["63c959f37337160e2de8b7e4/20230122173537/profilepicture.png","63c959f37337160e2de8b7e4/20230122173616/profilepicture.png"]
const indexOfElementToRemove = pfps.indexOf("63c959f37337160e2de8b7e4/20230122173537/profilepicture.png");
pfps.splice(indexOfElementToRemove, 1);
console.log(pfps);
```

Comment: Im sorry if my question was unclear :/. But thanks your method works!

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the element itself. [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) expects an index as first parameter. You should use [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the filter() method.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
let pfps = ["63c959f37337160e2de8b7e4/20230122173537/profilepicture.png","63c959f37337160e2de8b7e4/20230122173616/profilepicture.png"]
pfps = pfps.filter(item => item!="63c959f37337160e2de8b7e4/20230122173616/profilepicture.png");
```